# How do I tell whether an update will require an initramfs update?

Tags: apt, initramfs

Sometimes, when running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, towards the end there are lines like:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.103-v7+
```

How do you tell in advance if this is going to happen?

(The particular context I'm in is Raspberry Pi OS, but I believe this question is applicable to all Debian-based/apt-based OSes.)

Answer (score 4):

Run `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)` (or equivalent for your distribution) to see a list of all the things contained in *your* initramfs. If any of the corresponding files in the regular filesystem are changed, then initramfs should generally be updated too.

Note that some initramfs scripts have their correspondents in a different location in the real filesystem: in particular, the contents of the initramfs `/scripts` directory are based on files in both `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` and `/etc/initramfs-tools` in the real filesystem.

In particular, initramfs update is needed whenever:

- an updated kernel is installed
- if you have third-party kernel modules that are needed in early boot (i.e. drivers for your system disk, console display and/or keyboard) and those modules are updated (e.g. using DKMS)
- the scripts responsible for creating the actual initramfs contents, or the configuration files for those scripts, are changed
- any persistent settings related to the root filesystem, primary swap and/or resuming from hibernation are changed
- udev rules or kernel module options related to devices that are initialized within initramfs are changed

The first two of the above can often trigger automatic `update-initramfs` whenever the corresponding package is updated. The last two are mainly the responsibility of the system administrator.

If the `initramfs-tools` package is updated, the package maintainer normally configures the package to trigger an automatic `update-initramfs` as required. But if you make your own changes or additions to `initramfs-tools` hook scripts or configuration files, you are responsible for running it yourself.

Note that ideally you should keep your changes to initramfs-tools in `/etc/initramfs-tools/` sub-tree if at all possible; if you modify existing scripts in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/` sub-tree, those changes are likely to get overridden on package updates.

(If you absolutely have to make a modification to the standard scripts of initramfs-tools, you may wish to read the man page of `dpkg-divert` and use it to protect your changes.)

Comment: "If any of the corresponding files in the regular filesystem are changed, then initramfs should generally be updated too."

This doesn't take into account the modification of eg hooks and scripts in /usr/share/initramfs-tools.

Comment: One might argue it's just that the correspondence between initramfs and the real filesystem is just a bit more complex with those files :-) but that's a good point, edited.